# Node.JS TypeError: result.setPet is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So, I'm new to Node.JS, and this project is a simple petshop, with pets table, services offered, and appointments (when a certain service is applied to a certain pet in a certain date in the future).

Appointments have a petId and serviceId, each appointment must have only one of those, but pets and services can be referenced in multiple appointments.

This project was originally made with pure MySql, with separate repositories to handle queries, later I changed it to use sequelize ORM.

I've made the basics crud operations using the rest architecture, everything ok with the services and pets methods (post, get, patch, delete), but the problem began when trying to make post method with appointments, since appointments have serviceId and petId.

index.js

```
const customExpress = require('./config/customExpress');
const connection = require('./infrastructure/database/connection');


connection.sync()
.then(() => {
  console.log('Successfully connected to database')
  const app = customExpress()
  app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running at port 3000'))
})
.catch(erro => console.log('Something went wrong while trying to synchronize to database'))
```

connection.js
here is where the associations between tables and models are made, I think the error might be here, but can't figure out where

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const config = require('config')
const { applyExtraSetup } = require('../../models/extraSetup')


const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.get('mysql.database'),
    config.get('mysql.user'),
    config.get('mysql.password'),
    {
    host:config.get('mysql.host'),
    dialect:config.get('mysql.dialect')
    }
)

const modelDefiners = [
    require('../../models/appointments'),
    require('../../models/pets'),
    require('../../models/services'),
]
// it gets the models definitions and pass the above instance of sequelize to them
for (const modelDefiner of modelDefiners){
    modelDefiner(sequelize)
}
// and then make their relations with extra setup
applyExtraSetup(sequelize)
.then(module.exports = sequelize)
```

the extraSetup.js, makes the relations

```
// it exports the things the sequelize instance must do
async function applyExtraSetup(sequelize){
    const { appointments, services, pets } = sequelize.models

    await appointments.belongsTo(services)
    await appointments.belongsTo(pets)
    await services.hasMany(appointments)
    await pets.hasMany(appointments)
}

module.exports = { applyExtraSetup }
```

and this is appointment.js, a controller that handles the /appointments route and call the sequelize methods

```
app.post('/appointment', async (req, res) => {

        const data = req.body
        const pet = await Pets.findAll({ where : { name : req.body.petId }})
        const service = await Service.findAll({ where : { name : req.body.serviceId }})
        const appointment = Appointment.create(data)
        .then(result => {
                result.setPet(pet)
                res.end()

            })
```

reading sequelize documentation, I saw that with this type of association, you get magic methods to handle data from the related tables, which you call from an instance of a model (setPet, getPet, and so on).

Can anyone help me?

edit, models definitions (they're together since I'm refactoring the code, but originally each one was in a separate module):

```
exports.appointment = (sequelize) => { 
    const now = new Date()
    const Appointment = sequelize.define('appointments', {
        client: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        creationDate: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: now
        },
        date: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                isBefore: now
            }
        },
        status: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,        
            allowNull: false
        },
        observations: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }
        })
    return Appointment
}

exports.pets = (sequelize) => { 
    const Pets = sequelize.define('pets', {
        name : {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        image: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
    })
    return Pets
}

exports.service = (sequelize) => {
    const Service = sequelize.define('services', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        price: {
            type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
            allowNull: false
        }
    })
    return Service
}
```

Comment: Can you add model definitions as well?

Comment: sure, I'll edit
now, I'm refactoring it to put all model definitions in a single module, and then manage them through independent module with classes

Comment: So `result.setPet(pet)` throws an error or what? And also don't mix up `await` and `then/catch`. Use `await` only (at least in this case)

Comment: yes, it throws TypeError: result.setPet is not a function

Comment: Look at `result` and see if it has any functions starting with `set` in their names

Comment: it doesn't but it should, according to the documentation, since it is an instance of a model (confirmed by instanceof)

Comment: Then check if associations of this model were registered properly

Comment: yes, probably something went wrong bc I made model definitions in separate modules, and then required them to setup associations in another module (connections), I'll try to make all definitions and associations in a single module now